# Typescript: How to provide arguments to dynamically executed function

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export class MyClass {
    myFuncA(msg){console.log('A: '+msg); console.log('this: ',this);}

    myFuncB(msg){console.log('B: '+msg); console.log('this: ',this);}
}
```

I have a class instance called `mc`; I need a way to execute a dynamically named function of a `Typescript` class.

This executes the function properly:

```
export class CallingClass {
    constructor(){
        let mc = new MyClass();
        mc['myFuncA'].call(); // outputs 'A: undefined' 'this: undefined'
    }
}
```

I have 3 questions:

1. How can I provide arguments? `mc['myFuncA'].call('message')` doesn't work
2. How can I set `this` to be the `CallingClass`? `mc[...].call(...).bind(this)` errors
3. How can I set `this` to be the `MyClass`?

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zNFf7Qxl0YXMu2PBYdy7?p=preview)

Comment: read documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: @BryanChen Thanks Bryan that was helpful. Don't know why I thought it would be complicated. Do you care enough to write a solution so I can select it? Otherwise I'll write my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation for [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> How can I provide arguments? mc['myFuncA'].call('message') doesn't work

Just like normal function call

```
mc['myFuncA']('message')
```

or if you really want to use `call`

```
mc['myFuncA'].call(mc, 'message')
```

> How can I set this to be the CallingClass? mc[...].call(...).bind(this) errors

pass it to `call` as first argument

```
mc['myFuncA'].call(this, 'message')
```

this is how you use bind

```
mc['myFuncA'].bind(this)('message')
```

> How can I set this to be the MyClass?

```
mc['myFuncA'].call(mc, 'message')
```

which is

```
mc['myFuncA']('message')
```